# Sprockets::CircularDependencyError application.js has already been required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, version-control, sprockets

In my application, I receive a Sprockets::CircularDependencyError application.js has already been required. This affects every page in my application because none of the JS loads. Note - this error occurred after a fairly complex merge.

My assumption (please correct me if I'm wrong) is that this error occurs because two different files require application.js. If so, in which files should I look to debug this error? How could I test my application to determine what files are already requiring application.js?

Thank you very much for any help. I'd be more than happy to supply any pertinent information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> "this error occurred after a fairly complex merge. "

I'm sure the conflict would surely be in the `application.js` file too.. After the merge you might not have removed the extra application.js.* file your version control creates for you, where both of them would be having line of `require tree` or something.. i.e. both requiring each other thus circular dependency.  Make sure there is no such extra file in that folder...

Comment: You're completely right, I didn't realize that it would load the application.js.orig. Thanks a lot!... I'll mark it as soon as stackoverflow lets me...

Comment: For me, it was codekit automatically minifying application.js. `rm app/assets/javascript/application.min.js` did the trick.